# Scala using regex with or syntax in match case statement

Tags: scala

Cab anyone tell me why this does not work and how to fix ?

```
val aorb = "(a|b)".r

aorb.findFirstIn("with a ")
res103: Option[String] = Some(a)

"with a " match { case aorb() => "have a or b" case _ => "None"}
res102: String = None
```

I expected the match statement to return "have a or b"

The actual problem is to try a series of matches on more complex regexes for an input and return a value on the first successful pattern.

Comment: To summarize senia's answer, it's *match*, not "search" or "find." The whole scrutinee string must be matched by the RE, not just some portion thereof.

Comment: That's a good mnemonic (honestly) if it were true.  On an unanchored regex, the unapply performs a `find`, in fact.

Comment: @som-snytt: Sorry, that is not true. The extractor / `unapply` in Scala's `Regex` class, which is what's at play here, is inherently anchored at both ends.

Comment: @RandallSchulz I mean UnanchoredRegex overrides runMatcher, which is used by unapplySeq.

Comment: @RandallSchulz I only got into that code because someone wanted to deprecate unapply(Any), and I wondered what they meant... https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/util/matching/Regex.scala#L193

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An "anchored" regex for pattern matching matches whole inputs:

```
val aorb = ".*(a|b).*".r

"with a " match {
  case aorb(_) => "have a or b"
  case _ => "None"
}
// res0: String = have a or b
```

If you have capturing groups in your regex you should also use or explicitly ignore results: note `_` in `aorb(_)`.

Comment: Thanks, the _ placeholder for groups is a key part I had missed as well

Comment: This answer suggests that you have to match the whole string and you have to capture groups, but see the other answer.

Comment: Sorry I came in at the end of the day.  I am somewhat consoled by the fact that the upvoted and green-checked answer, while not the whole truth, isn't actually wrong or perverse, as happens sometimes in life on SO. And I mean perverse not in a good way.

Comment: @som-snytt: I didn't know about `UnanchoredRegex`, thank you. By the way: as you can see from my profile "the end of the day" is about "3 AM" for me.

Comment: Hey, me too!  I mean local time. (But strictly temporary jet lag.) For Scala questions, I think of COB (close of business) as when Mitteleuropa has its last beer.

Answer (score 8):

The behavior you seek is:

```
scala> val aorb = "(a|b)".r
aorb: scala.util.matching.Regex = (a|b)

scala> val aorbs = aorb.unanchored
aorbs: scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex = (a|b)

scala> "with a or b" match { case aorbs(x) => Some(x) case _ => None }
res0: Option[String] = Some(a)
```

For testing just a `find`, don't capture the group:

```
scala> val aorbs = "(?:a|b)".r.unanchored
aorbs: scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex = (?:a|b)

scala> "with a or b" match { case aorbs() => true case _ => false }
res4: Boolean = true

scala> import PartialFunction._
import PartialFunction._

scala> cond("with a or b") { case aorbs() => true }
res5: Boolean = true
```

Update: this is probably obvious, but a sequence wildcard matches whatever capture groups:

```
scala> val aorb = "(a|b).*(c|d)".r.unanchored
aorb: scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex = (a|b).*(c|d)

scala> "either an a or d" match { case aorb(_) => true case _ => false }
res0: Boolean = false

scala> "either an a or d" match { case aorb(_*) => true case _ => false }
res1: Boolean = true
```

For regular `unapply`, `case p()` matches on `true`.  For `unapplySeq`, the implementation can return a `Seq` or a tuple with the `Seq` in last position.  The regex unapply returns a `Seq` of the matching groups, or `Nil` if nothing is captured.

Comment: The initial answer solved my immediate concern so I accepted it. This one is a more complete solution which I will use. In the future I will wait a little longer before accepting an answer to see if something more appropriate arises. Thanks

Comment: @Gavin Getting it done is laudable, the perfect is enemy of the good, premature optimization is the root of all slipped deadlines.  I think we're supposed to work on improving the green check, actually, to produce the best answers. So the initial race to come up with an ok answer is healthy competition to generate ideas.