# Scala regex "starts with lowercase alphabets" not working

Tags: regex, scala

```
val AlphabetPattern = "^([a-z]+)".r

def stringMatch(s: String) = s match {
 case AlphabetPattern() => println("found")
 case _ => println("not found")
}
```

If I try,

```
stringMatch("hello")
```

I get "not found", but I expected to get "found".

My understanding of the regex,

[a-z] = in the range of 'a' to 'z' 
+     = one more of the previous pattern 
^     = starts with

So regex AlphabetPattern is "all strings that start with one or more alphabets in the range a-z"

Surely I am missing something, want to know what.

Comment: Keep in mind you don't need the `^` (nor would you need a `$`). The Regex matching using in `match` is a, uh... match. Not a find / search. I.e., it's inherently anchored at both ends. To get a find-like behavior, you need to put a `.*` at one or both ends.

Comment: This is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/17572225/1296806, where it was also answered incorrectly. @RandallSchulz see that answer.

Comment: Sorry @RandallSchulz (lack of sleep talking), what I meant was that the mnemonic for "match" omits unanchored behavior, which is an easy use case for the API that needs advertising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `case AlphabetPattern()` with `case AlphabetPattern(_)` and it works. The extractor pattern takes a variable to which it binds the result. Here we discard it but you could use `x` or whatever.

edit: Further to Randall's comment below, if you check the [docs for `Regex`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex) you'll see that it has an `unapplySeq` rather than an `unapply` method, which means it takes multiple variables. If you have the wrong number, it won't match, rather like

```
list match { case List(a,b,c) => a + b + c }
```

won't match if `list` doesn't have exactly 3 elements.

Comment: In general, the number of pattern variables (here the single `_`) must exactly match the number of capturing groups in the `Regex`'s `Pattern`. You could also make your code work by turning the parens in the pattern into a non-capturing group: `(?:[a-z]+)`

Comment: hooray for non-capturing. Rah for unanchored.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the match statement. `s match` is matching on the value of `s` which is checked against `AlphabetPattern` and `_` which always evaluates to `_` since `s` is never equal to  `"^([a-z]+)".r`. Use one of the `find` methods in `Scala.Util.Regex` to look for a match with the given `Regex.

For example, using `findFirstIn` to find the first match of a string in `AlphabetPattern`.

```
scala> AlphabetPattern.findFirstIn("hello")
res0: Option[String] = Some(hello)
```

The `stringMatch` method using `findFirstIn` and a case statement:

```
scala> def stringMatch(s: String) = AlphabetPattern findFirstIn s match {
     | case Some(s) => println("Found: " + s)
     | case None => println("Not found")
     | }

stringMatch: (s:String)Unit                                   

scala> stringMatch("hello")                           
Found: hello
```